# SQL Server strange ROUND() behaviour

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rounding

I have a huge table of product rows... I only need a small portion of its data, more specifically the prices of the products (regular price - for which I have to choose between two fields in the sense that if one is present, I pick it, otherwise I pick the other; and sale price - which for many products is stored as a float with three decimals, because it was calculated as a percentage of the regular price). So I crafted the appropriate query to achieve what I want, and noticed a very strange behavior for the ROUND() function.

In some cases, when the third decimal digit is 5 (ie. .165) is truncated to .16 and in others it's rounded up to .17, and this happens for any other number with 5 at the third decimal place as well of course! How can that be possible? Here is the query:

```
SELECT CODE, FWHSPRICE, RTLPRICE, CASE WHEN ISNULL(FWHSPRICE, 0) = 0 THEN RTLPRICE ELSE FWHSPRICE END AS REGULAR, ROUND(FLDFLOAT3, 2) AS SALE
FROM MATERIAL
WHERE COMID = 12
AND FLTID1 = 1
```

And here is a screenshot of a comparison between the two recordsets, on the left without ROUND() in the query, and on the right with ROUND()

[image]

PS: If you want me to export data for replication, can you please explain to me how to create the appropriate INSERT statements for you? The whole table has so many fields - and rows, and I don't know how to set SSMS to do that. I'm coming from MySQL, so this "realm" of SQL Server is so new to me... Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't use `float` if accuracy is important to you. REF: [float and real (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql) _Approximate-number data types for use with floating point numeric data. Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in the data type range can be represented exactly._

Comment: @AlwaysLearning OK, I understand that, but how can .615 be rounded once at .61 and then .415 to .42? Also, unfortunately, this isn't a DB I've made... It's from a desktop merchant (sales) application, and I can't touch its fields in terms of type changes etc...

Comment: Again, because float is approximate. Consider: `select round(0.615e0, 2), round(1.615e0, 2), round(2.615e0, 2), round(3.615e0, 2);` which results in `0.61, 1.61, 2.62, 3.62`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning nice, [added those examples here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d4a8988a266b4fbcb71a22090401b3a5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you're mixing two things that have their own sets of quirky behavior (IMHO). I would honestly just not use `float` unless I needed the specific properties of float, but if you're stuck with this data type...

I would first convert from `float` to `decimal` with an extra decimal place (or maybe even 2), then use another convert to round instead of round itself. For example:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(x float);

INSERT @x(x) VALUES(0.615),(0.165),(0.415),(0.414);

SELECT 
  x, 
  bad    = ROUND(x, 2), 
  better = CONVERT(decimal(10,2), CONVERT(decimal(10,3), x))
FROM @x;
```

Results:

| x | bad | better |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.615 | 0.61 | 0.62 |
| 0.165 | 0.17 | 0.17 |
| 0.415 | 0.41 | 0.42 |
| 0.414 | 0.41 | 0.41 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf484859c3d8a9e39ad5dd277801cb29)

If you have values like `0.4149`, you can see how an extra decimal place will prevent that from rounding up (unless that's the behavior you want):

```
DECLARE @f float = 0.4149;

SELECT source     = @f,
       round_up   = CONVERT(decimal(10,2), CONVERT(decimal(10,3), @f)),
       round_down = CONVERT(decimal(10,2), CONVERT(decimal(10,4), @f));
```

Results:

| source | round_up | round_down |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.4149 | 0.42 | 0.41 |

Comment: That indeed solved the problem! Thank you, thank you, thank you so very much!

Comment: Totally off-topic, but how could I apply this 2-decimal formatting technique to the `REGULAR` field which is calculated like so `CASE WHEN ISNULL(FWHSPRICE, 0) = 0 THEN RTLPRICE ELSE FWHSPRICE END AS REGULAR`?

Comment: This is an extract of the resultset
| CODE | FWHSPRICE | RTLPRICE | REGULAR | FLDFLOAT3 | SALE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000468507 | 0 | 43 | 43 | 34,4 | 34.40 |
| 001195501 | 0 | 48 | 48 | 38,4 | 38.40 |
| 001460500 | 0 | 19,9 | 19,9 | 16,915 | 16.92 |
| 001611566 | 0 | 48 | 48 | 38,4 | 38.40 |
| 002309103 | 0 | 21,9 | 21,9 | 18,615 | 18.62 |
| 1B32241-R | 0 | 21 | 21 | 16,8 | 16.80 |
| 1LS91101-421 | NULL | 48 | 48 | 33,6 | 33.60 |
| 2A466072 | 0 | 37 | 37 | 29,6 | 29.60 |
| 343880-028 | 0 | 29,9 | 29,9 | 25,415 | 25.42 |

Comment: @FayeD Can you please build an example with the real table structure, source data types, sample data, and desired results using [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk)? Understanding the data from a comment or a screenshot is next to impossible.

Comment: Sure, just give me a moment please!

Comment: If I'm understanding your question I _think_ you just mean `REGULAR = CONVERT(decimal(10,2), CONVERT(decimal(10,4), CASE WHEN ISNULL(FWHSPRICE, 0) = 0 THEN RTLPRICE ELSE FWHSPRICE END))`

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=382acaead0d363cd391a82de3f0a3204 
Sorry for taking so long to respond. I want the field `REGULAR` in this fiddle to have 2 decimals, like the `SALE` with your indirect rounding technique!

Comment: Ah, it was that simple! The time to create the fiddle was 5x times the time it would take me to try a couple of experiments until it'd work for me! Hehe

Comment: I'm returning to this, as I noticed that for some prices the field is empty. So in order to return those as 0.00, I changed `CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,3), prod.FLDFLOAT3)) AS SALE,` to `CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,3), ISNULL(prod.FLDFLOAT3, 0))) AS SALE,` but this doesn't work as intended, as for those products the sale price is returned as `.00` - the decimal part is omitted. What is wrong with this?

Comment: @Faye can you please add rows that produce "empty" to the [fiddle you created](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=382acaead0d363cd391a82de3f0a3204) and generate a new fiddle from that so we can understand why? Also where are you seeing `.00`, is this how the output is displayed in some tool or application? What if you say `COALESCE(prod.FLDFLOAT3, 0.00)`? [I can't reproduce the problem, FWIW](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6f63e622be91253426c92f98c002e924), so I would guess this is how your application has decided to display 0.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fe4072726b91e83bc0f6f87e1df3e874

Comment: Again @FayeD. I'm not sure exactly where the breakdown is. Removing several noise rows: [new fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=69d0f8a85866f63b924a432515b6eb45) - if the second example there isn't returning what you want, please try explaining again what you expect and how it is different.

Comment: indeed in the fiddle it's working fine!!!!! https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fe4072726b91e83bc0f6f87e1df3e874

Very strange behavior of PHP displaying it as `.00`
I'll investigate this further. Sorry for the false alarm Aaron! Thanks a lot for everything!

Comment: Yeah, PHP does a lot of things in, um, interesting ways.

Comment: I was able to find the issue... It's the MS driver (sqlsrv_) that's causing it... It's discussed here: https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/415 and especially around here https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/415#issuecomment-445907544 is the most interesting part of the issue. You simply have to add this option `'FormatDecimals' => true` in the options of the `sqlsrv_connect` command https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Comment: Sorry @FayeD. I am not familiar with that issue or how you might address it (other than returning the formatted value as a string so that PHP doesn’t even know it was ever a number).

Comment: It's OK, I was able to find it myself! Posting it here just to help others should they face the same issue! The relevant MS resource can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/formatting-decimals-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15